# How to assign data to variable in component?

Tags: angular, angular7

I have core component:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor() {

       const toast: any = {
        type: exception.type,
        body: ToasterRenderComponent.messages = ["44"],
        bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.Component
      };

      this.toasterService.pop(toast);
   }
}
```

In constructor I try to fill object `toast` and assign data to variable of component `ToasterRenderComponent`:

```
ToasterRenderComponent.messages = ["44"]
```

Component `ToasterRenderComponent` has public property `messages`, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Seems I should create instance of `ToasterRenderComponent`

Comment: I tried: `body: new ToasterRenderComponent().messages = ["Message1"],`

Comment: Error is: `ToasterContainerComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: No component factory found for [sfsdfsdsdf]. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at noComponentFactoryError...`

Comment: This is  component, I try to use component for toaster: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster`

Comment: You should create a service exposing an Observable and methods like `AddToast()` and `clear()`. Your toaster should subscribe to the observable, and your other components should use the methods to update the data that should be displayed by your toaster.

Comment: No ways to assign data to property of component outside?

Comment: It looks like you're not really understanding the difference between a class and an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';    
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(private router: Router) {    
       const toast: any = {
        type: exception.type,
        body: ToasterRenderComponent.messages = ["44"],
        bodyOutputType: BodyOutputType.Component
      };    
      this.router.config.find(r => r.component== ToasterRenderComponent).data = toast;
   }
}
```

in component "ToasterRenderComponent"

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';    
export class ToasterRenderComponent implements OnInit {
  toasterObject: any;
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.data.subscribe(r=>this.toasterObject=r);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When working with cross component data transmission there are a on the top of my head two primary ways to do it depending on the relationship between the components.

- If the components views are not nested (not parent and child), then the natural approach would be to create an Angular [service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4).
- If the components are nested, one would usually pass data through [template data binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction).

Of course there are work-arounds, however to ensure that Angular destroys components correctly I'd suggest sticking to what the documentation states.